# Find nearest all other android device ip address within my wifi network?

Tags: android, sockets, ip, chat, android-wifi

I am developing a chat App within local network. Here i am done with socket chat. But still could not find to get nearest device's ip address within my wifi range.

Scenario: Installed my chat App in 4 devices. It's all connected with my wifi. Now i need to show other 3 device ip address in 4th device.

Note: If not clear with my doubt, please comment me. I will explain you.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need a server for this. Whenever a user connects to a wifi & runs your app, you need to store the username, his IP & the wifi BSSID on a server. By doing this, you can fetch a list of users who are connected to same wifi.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Thanks for your response. I can store user's ip in server. But, How could I get list user's ip in same network using php?

Comment: you need to use the Wifi BSSID that I mentioned. This ID uniquely identifies a Wifi Router. So all the users having same BSSID shall be connected to the same network.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=uwI8VIGCHerA8geFnoDwAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=Wifi+BSSID

Comment: @Eu.Dr. Oh great. Now i got a solution. Thanks for your response.